# Convergence of $\int_2^\infty \left[\left(0.99 - \frac{1}{x^2}\right)^x\cdot\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)\right]dx$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm taking a calculus course and I was show this improper integral in class. the Professor told us that this integral converges and left us to prove it as a challenge. The thing is, I can't find a series that converges as well that could help me prove this integral converges and the integral itself is a bit of a handful so I couldn't integrate it directly as well.

This is the intgral: $$\int_2^\infty \left[\left(0.99 - \frac{1}{x^2}\right)^x\cdot\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)\right]dx$$

I would really aprricate a hint to the way of proving this, so far I have tried comparing it with other known integrals/series, altering the function to $e^{xln(0.99-\frac{1}{x^2}) + ln(\frac{x-1}{x})}$ and then integrating it, also tried deriving $xln(0.99-\frac{1}{x^2}) + ln(\frac{x-1}{x})$ and show that it's limit is $-\infty$ but all these ways led me to a dead end.

Thanks in advance to all who share their wisdom!

Comment: $\frac {x-1} x$ is bounded and $r^{x}$ is integrable if $0<r<1$.

Comment: then would it be correct to claim that $\left(0.99 - \frac{1}{x^2}\right)^x\cdot\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right) \leq \left(0.99 - \frac{1}{x^2}\right)^x$ ? Or vice versa?

Comment: Also less than $(0.99)^{x}=e^{-cx}$ wher $c=-\ln (0.99)$ is a positive number.

Answer (score 1):

Since @Kavi Rama Murthy already provided all the elements, let me consider the more genral case of
$$I(\epsilon)=\int_2^\infty \left(1-\epsilon - \frac{1}{x^2}\right)^x\,\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)\,dx$$ where $\epsilon \ll 1$.

At the lower bound the integrand is already small $\left(\frac{(3-4 \epsilon )^2}{32}\right)$

Take the logarithm of the integrand and expand it as a series for large values of $x$
$$\log\Bigg[ \left(1-\epsilon - \frac{1}{x^2}\right)^x\,\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)\Bigg]=x\log(1-\epsilon)+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
$$\left(1-\epsilon - \frac{1}{x^2}\right)^x\,\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)\sim (1-\epsilon)^x $$
So,
$$I(\epsilon)\sim\int_2^\infty (1-\epsilon)^x \,dx=-\frac{(1-\epsilon )^2}{\log (1-\epsilon )}=\frac{1}{\epsilon }-\frac{5}{2}+\frac{23 \epsilon }{12}-\frac{3 \epsilon
   ^2}{8}+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$$ For $\epsilon=\frac 1{100}$ the truncated series would give, as an *approximation*,
$$I\left(\frac{1}{100}\right)=\frac{23404591}{240000} \sim 97.5191$$ while the numerical integration would lead to $91.3737$.

For $\epsilon=\frac 1{1000}$, the series would give $997.502$ while the numerical integration would lead to $986.852$.